# Кодировка UTF-8 в html странице

Tags: linux, кодировка, сервер, google-chrome, utf-8

Есть `index.html`, который, при запуске локально (chrome, IE), отображается корректно.

При загрузке на виртуальный сервер, и открытии через Chrome - абракадабра.
Через IE - все ок (вероятно, IE подстраивается под необходимую кодировку, хотя в кодировке так же - `UTF-8`).

В `head` есть строка:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Но wget возвращает: `charset=CP1251`. Почему?

Возможно, нужно поменять что-то на сервере? Сервер linux, uhttpd

Comment: да, вероятно, надо заменить заголовок content-type на актуальный. посмотрите, что возвращает, например, этот сайт: `$ wget -S --spider http://stackoverflow.com |& grep -i content-type`

Comment: Вернуло:
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Соответственно, у меня и стоит utf-8. Поэтому, никак не могу понять, в чем проблема. Попробовал поменять на: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"> - не помогло. (в таком режиме корректно работают php страницы на сервере).

Comment: Я сделал команду выше на свой сайт, вернуло: text/html; charset=CP1251 . Хотя в index.html стоит UTF-8. Видимо в этом и ошибка. Почему так может быть?

Comment: *Почему так может быть?* — вероятно, так настроен ваш http-сервер. кстати, это может быть совсем и не *uhttpd*, а, например, какой-нибудь прокси-сервер. посмотрите другие возвращаемые заголовки (убрав из предложенной команды всё, начиная с `|`).

Comment: Немного погуглить и вот ответы [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server) [2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/130511/)

Comment: @VyacheslavGroshenkov вы как администрируете сервер? через панель управления(если да, то через какую) или вручную?

Comment: Администрирую через PuTTy + WinSCP, сервер виртуальный. Действительно,  Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat) PHP/5.4.32. Файл .htaccess не нашел. Httpd.conf тоже. Искал под root. Проблема все еще актуальна :(

Comment: @VyacheslavGroshenkov тут смотрели? `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` если не найдёте там, побалуйтесь командой `find / -name имя_искомого_файла` пример `find / -name httpd.*` Удачи.

Comment: .htaccess под умолчанию отсутствует. если в конфиграции сервера кодировка не та, то в каталоге где у вас index.html создайте сами .htacess и напишите в него `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`. А настройки апача обычно в /etc/apache

Comment: Да, и не забывайте, что файлы начинающиеся с точки в *nix системе являются скрытыми. ИЗ командной строки их покажет только `ls -a`

Comment: @Mike оформите как ответ, пожалуйста

Comment: Либо браузер не поддерживает html5, либо не распознаёт таковой в Вашем index.html, либо там вовсе не UTF-8. wget, кстати, знает о html5? В старом html кодировка задаётся так `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: @banme да у него сервер присылает кривой заголовок Content-Type. и уже все равно что написано в теле страницы.

Comment: @PashaPash Разве? Я всегда считал, что html может перебить таким образом заголовок сервера. Но проверять это никогда не возникало желания.

Comment: @banme заголовок и BOM приоритетнее: This <meta> element is only a part of the algorithm to determine the character set of a page that browsers apply. The HTTP Content-Type header and any BOM elements have precedence over this element. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

Comment: @PashaPash Ну раз мозилла говорит "have", то поверю на слово. Спасибо за труд.

Comment: @PashaPash ответ добавил. То что html может перебить заголовок, да так в общем то когда то было, но потом был период полной чехарды, когда браузеры не могли угадать кодировку из-за особенностей web-серверов тех времен и в итоге большинство браузеров считает Content-type приоритетней.

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте в какой кодировке сам документ `index.html` Откройте его к примеру в `Notepad++` вкладка КОДИРОВКА и выберете `UTF8` без `BOM`. После перезалейте на сервер.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в кодировке, отдаваемой сервером в заголовках (Content-type). Ее можно изменить в конфигурационном файле сервера (для apache httpd.conf), или в случаях, если он не доступен на хостинге или поддерживает сайты в разных кодировках, то надо использовать файл `.htaccess` в корневой папке Вашего сайта (там, где index.html и т.п.)
Если файла .htaccess нет, то просто создайте его. В нем надо указать строку:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```