# Не работает кириллица на сайте

Tags: html5

здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой не работы кириллицы на сайте.
я скачал готовый шаблон там было на немецком, кажется, языке.Я естественно поставил кодировку utf-8

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

но у меня все равно кириллица отображается как знак вопроса в ромбе
создал еще одну страницы скопировав скелет страницы там точно так же установив кодировку все символы корректно отображаются. Подскажите, с чем это может быть связано

Comment: Может быть, что в css друая кодировка, и получается не состыковка. Вторая страница  точная копия первой?

Comment: посмотрите http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463458/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-utf-8-%D0%B2-html-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5/465734#465734

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Файл нужно сохранить тоже в utf-8, а не какой-то другой кодировке. Скорее всего сам файл не соответствует utf-8, удостоверьтесь в этом.